# plt.hist() vs np.histogram() - unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, binning

The following lines

```
a1, b1, _ = plt.hist(df['y'], bins='auto')
a2, b2 = np.histogram(df['y'], bins='auto')

print(a1 == a2)
print(b1 == b2)
```

equate to all values of `a1` being equal to those of `a2` and the same for `b1` and `b2`

I then create a plot using `pyplot` alone (using `bins=auto` [should use the same `np.histogram()` function](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)):

```
plt.hist(df['y'], bins='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I then try to achieve the same histogram, but by calling `np.histogram()` myself, and passing the results into `plt.hist()`, but I get a blank histogram:

```
a2, b2 = np.histogram(df['y'], bins='auto')
plt.hist(a2, bins=b2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

From how I understand that `plt.hist(df['y'], bins='auto')` works, these two plots I am creating should be exactly the same - why isn't my method of using `Numpy` working?

**EDIT**

Following on from @MSeifert's answer below, I believe that for

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(df['y'], bins='auto')
```

`bins` is a list of the starting value for each bin, and `counts` is the corresponding number of values in each of these bins. As shown from my histogram above, this should produce a nearly perfect normal distribution, however, if call `print(counts, bins)` [the result of `counts`](https://pastebin.com/WeSuBZ25) shows that the very first and last bins have quite a substantial count of ~11,000. Why isn't this reflected in the histogram - why is there not two large spikes at either tail?

**EDIT 2**

It was just a resolution issue and my plot was seemingly too small for the spikes at either end to render correctly. Zooming in allowed them to display.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're assuming that `plt.hist` can differentiate between an array containing **counts as values** and an array **containing values to count**.

However that's not what happens, when you pass the counts to `plt.hist` it will count them and place them in the provided bins. That can lead to empty histograms but also to weird histograms.

So while `plt.hist` and `numpy.histogram` both work the same you cannot just pass the data obtained from `numpy.histogram` to `plt.hist` because that would count the counts of the values (not what you expect):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
arr = np.random.normal(10, 3, size=1000)
cnts, bins = np.histogram(arr, bins='auto')
ax.hist(cnts, bins=bins)
```

[image]

However you can use a `bar` plot to vizualize histograms obtained by `numpy.histogram`:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
cnts, bins = np.histogram(arr, bins='auto')
ax1.bar(bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins) / 2, cnts, np.diff(bins))
ax2.hist(arr, bins='auto')
```

[image]

Comment: Upon further inspecting my data, I have become unsure of another related aspect to my original question. Please see my edit.

Comment: I really don't know why these don't display when you plot the histogram (they do show up at my computer - maybe it's a resolution thing). But I think that edit would be better as new question. It would get more attention and you don't mix several questions into one. Feel free to leave a link here, that sounds interesting and I would like to know the answer too :)

Comment: Ah yes, it is just a resolution issue. My plot was just initially too small, so when I zoom in or set it to fullscreen, the two spikes at the first and last bin show. Thanks.